# Oracle inequality for LASSO

Tags: least-squares, lasso, regularization, sparse

In chapter 6 of [Statistics for High Dimensional Data](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-20192-9) (Peter BühlmannSara van de Geer), they focus on the normal linear regression model with fixed regressors and begin by stating OLS achieves a risk
$\mathbb{E}\|X\hat{\beta}-X\beta^0\|^2_2/n=\sigma^2p/n$.

They then claim to show an oracle inequality for LASSO,

$\|X\hat{\beta}-X\beta^0\|^2_2/n\leq \text{const}\sigma^2(\log p)s_0/n$,

holding with high probability.

Just to clarify, does this oracle inequality demonstrate that LASSO is better than OLS in predictive power because of the sparsity assumption (i.e. $s_0$
is "small") making $s_0\log p$ grow slower than $p$.?

Comment: does the RHS of your inequality lower bound the loss of OLS? What is the loss of OLS?

Comment: the authors only compute the risk of OLS (instead of the loss)---presumably because the OLS estimator is random, so the expected value averages out the randomness and moreover, the expected value is easily computable in the normal lin reg model for OLS.